# Closed unbounded sets and partitions

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, partitions

Let $\kappa$ be a regular, uncountable cardinal.  Let $S\subseteq \kappa$ be a closed and unbounded set.  Suppose that we partition $S$ into $<\kappa$ pieces.  Does one of those pieces contain a closed and unbounded set?

Comment: If, instead of ZFC, you assume ZF + Axiom of Determinacy, then the answer is yes for $\kappa=\omega_1$.

Comment: @LajosSoukup That is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.  Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily. In fact, we can split $\kappa$ into $\kappa$-many disjoint stationary sets; this (and more) is due to Solovay, see "stationary splitting."

Comment: No set in such a splitting can include a club, because the other sets in the splitting are stationary.